# how to calculate the average of elements above a certain threshold in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to calculate the mean of the elements that are greater than a fixed threshold (here 0.8).

Task in numpy :

```
X = np.array([[0.11,0.99,0.70]])
print(np.nanmean(X[X>0.8]))
Out : 0.99
```

What is the equivalent in tensorflow without converting the tensor `c` to a numpy array?

Example:

```
c = tf.constant([[0.11,0.99,0.70]])
tf.reduce_mean(tf.where(tf.greater(c,(tf.constant(0.8, dtype=tf.float32)))))
```

the output is equal to 0!

```
Output : <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `tf.greater` and `tf.where`.

```
c = tf.constant([[0.11,0.99,0.70]])
# Or : tf.reduce_mean(c[c > 0.8])
tf.reduce_mean(c[c > tf.constant(0.8, dtype=tf.float32)])
```

You can use [`tf.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) as an alternative:

```
c = tf.constant([[0.11,0.99,0.70]])
mask = c > 0.8
tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask))
```

Output : `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.99>`

Comment: @l'mahdi thanks for your clear answer. How about np.nanmean(c>0.8) instead of  np.nanmean(c[c>0.8]) ?

Comment: @KKK07, you're welcome, the output of `c>0.8` is an array of `True` and `False`. Then when you compute the mean on this array, you compute the mean on `True` and `False`.

Comment: @l'mahdi Yes it's possible to do it in Numpy, but not at the same way in tensorflow (InvalidArgumentError)! the output will be 0.33 in this case.

Comment: @KKK07, Do you  want this : `tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(c > 0.8, dtype=tf.float32))`? the output is `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.33333334>`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `boolean_mask` instead of tensor indexing:

```
c = tf.constant([[0.11,0.99,0.70]])
tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(c, c > 0.8))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.99>
```